# Create range from 0 to 1 with step 0.05 in Numpy

Tags: numpy, python-3.6

I want create a list from `0` to `1` with step `0.05`, the result will like this: `[0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95, 1]`

I try with following code, but the output seems not correct. Anyone could help? Thanks.

```
print(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05).tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15000000000000002, 0.2, 0.25, 0.30000000000000004, 0.35000000000000003, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6000000000000001, 0.65, 0.7000000000000001, 0.75, 0.8, 0.8500000000000001, 0.9, 0.9500000000000001]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [`np.linspace()`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html)

```
np.linspace(0, 1, 21)
Out[]: 
array([0.  , 0.05, 0.1 , 0.15, 0.2 , 0.25, 0.3 , 0.35, 0.4 , 0.45, 0.5 ,
       0.55, 0.6 , 0.65, 0.7 , 0.75, 0.8 , 0.85, 0.9 , 0.95, 1.  ])
```

Comment: Hi Daniel. `np.linspace(0, 1, 21)[3]` still gets me `0.15000000000000002`. It appears as `0.15` when outputting the entire array, like in your example, but isn't that just an artifact of how it's summarized in the output? I don't see how `linspace` should be able to do any magic that deals with floating point precision issues. I believe you'll still need to do something like `np.around(np.linspace(0, 1, 21)[3], 3)` to deal with this. What am I missing?

Comment: Checking the history, it seems I answered within the "invisible edit" time window for the question.  I can't imagine I gave this answer to the question as asked now.  For dealing with the floating point errors, your solution (or the self-answer below) would probably be best.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary use .tolist().

Try this:

```py
a = np.arange(0, 1, 0.05)
print (a)
```

Output:

```py
[0.   0.05 0.1  0.15 0.2  0.25 0.3  0.35 0.4  0.45 0.5  0.55 0.6  0.65
 0.7  0.75 0.8  0.85 0.9  0.95]
```

Comment: OK, but I need to convert to a list anyway.

Comment: a = list(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05))
print (type(a))

Comment: Convert the result to list, you can check with type.

Comment: With your code I get, `[0.0,
 0.05,
 0.1,
 0.15000000000000002,
 0.2,
 0.25,
 0.30000000000000004,
 0.35000000000000003,
 0.4,
 0.45,
 0.5,
 0.55,
 0.6000000000000001,
 0.65,
 0.7000000000000001,
 0.75,
 0.8,
 0.8500000000000001,
 0.9,
 0.9500000000000001]`

Comment: Thats strange, if know the number of decimals you could round

Comment: Yes, this `np.arange(0, 1, 0.05).round(2).tolist()` or `list(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05).round(2))` solved my problem.

Comment: If you find out the technical reason of that comment

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47243190/numpy-arange-how-to-make-precise-array-of-floats

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580811/np-arange-does-not-work-as-expected-with-floating-point-arguments

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
print(np.arange(0, 1, 0.05).round(2).tolist())
```

Output:

```
[0.0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5, 0.55, 0.6, 0.65, 0.7, 0.75, 0.8, 0.85, 0.9, 0.95]
```