# Unexpected behavior of numpy.arange()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I would like to know what is the best way to overcome the unexpected behavior of `numpy.arange()` when floats are involved. In particular, I have identified 2 problems in the following example:

I need to discretize my time domain from 0 up until `t_max` (inclusive), with time steps `dt`. For that I define these two variables and redefine `dt` so the time vector is uniformly space, as follows.

```
t_max = 200    
dt = 0.07 
dt = t_max/np.ceil(t_max/dt)                  # dt = 0.06997900629811056
t = np.arange(0, t_max+dt, dt, dtype=float)   # so to have t = [0, 0.0699..., ..., 200]
```

The **1st problem** is that `t[-1] = 199.99999999999997`, because `t_max/dt = 2858.0000000000005` (`dt` redefined), and not `2858.0` as expected.

The **2nd problem** is that related to the use of floats, in this case `dt`. I usually use the suggestion in [np.arange does not work as expected with floating point arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53580811/np-arange-does-not-work-as-expected-with-floating-point-arguments). I arbitraly chose `0.5` because it is half-way through not getting `t_max` (that I want) and getting `t_max+dt` (that I don't want), but this seems a bit odd.

```
t = np.arange(0, t_max/dt+0.5, 1, dtype=float)*dt
```

In Matlab all this seems to work with a simple `t = 0:dt:t_max;`.

In my case, this is an issue because logical tests like in the case below will fail when I expect them to return true. Most of the times it is handy to work with `x_max`, but the real figure is `x[-1]` (as all the code is based on my time domain).

```
x_max = v*t_max
x = v*t
x_max == x[-1]   # False
```

I refer to [Python: Range or numpy Arange with end limit include](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50299172/python-range-or-numpy-arange-with-end-limit-include), where a good alternative is given. However, the function provided does not handle my `dt = 0.06997900629811056` (it just gets 0.07), so I am a bit concerned about using it.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html), it **is** the expected behavior. *When using a non-integer step, such as 0.1, the results will often not be consistent. It is better to use numpy.linspace for these cases.*.

Comment: @QuangHoang, I know the 2nd issue is documented and I can use numpy.linspace, but then I am concerned the time steps my differ from my calculated dt.

Comment: Does `total = np.ceil(t_max/dt); t=np.linspace(0,t_max, int(total)+1)` work for you?

Comment: That is what I'm doing with ```dt = t_max/np.ceil(t_max/dt) ```. I could use ```np.ceil(t_max/dt)``` to get the number of divisions in ```numpy.linspace```, but then I may transfer my problem involving non-matching ```t_max``` vs ```t[-1]``` to non-matching ```dt``` vs ```(spacing in linspace array)```.

Comment: In regards to the first problem, the reason you are getting ```2858.0000000000005``` and not ```2858.0``` is because of floating point precision. I think by default the division will round off to a 64 bit float. Running ```np.divide(t_max, dt, dtype=np.float32)``` you will see that it does equal ```2858.0```.

Comment: You said the problem is documented, but you don't seem to follow the suggestion. `linspace` works pretty well, `t[-1]` is exactly `200`.

Comment: I was trying not to do many changes in my code and keeping the arange's. I agree with you @QuangHoang, that linspace is the alternative. Also having the exact ```t_max``` is more critical than the exact ```dt```. @Kevin also added a valid point which may solve may issues.

Comment: Python, and numpy especially, do no support arbitrary precision floats. That means that if your spacing can not be expressed exactly in 53 bits, you can either round the spacing or the bounds. The decision is up to you. There is no magic in this world.

Comment: I've read the comments, and I think they don't express strongly enough that this is not a wise approach overall. Floating point numbers generally don't line up to the exact bit, and relying on quirks of `arange` vs `linspace`, etc, is just going to lead to frustration and errors. And these quirks aren't generally guaranteed, so even if you get it to work for your test using `0.5`, it may not work with `0.51`; or it may work now but not after your next update; etc.